# Scroll scrollview with seekbar and finger android

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the scrollview position and progress either from sliding up and down with fingers or by moving the scrollbar view with seekbar ?

Answer (score 0):

See code example:

```
...    
yourLinearLayoutInScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new LayoutOnTouchListener());
...

private class LayoutOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Point realTouchPosition = new Point(Math.round(motionEvent.getX() + view.getScrollX()), Math.round(motionEvent.getY() + view.getScrollY()));

            return false;
        }
    }
```